# Use go-ethereum libraries to subscribe to pending transactions in code

Tags: go, ethereum, go-ethereum

I've been reading geth's source code for the better part of a week and it's making my head spin.
I'm trying to subscribe to see any interactions with a given contract in a go project with imported go-ethereum libraries. Please help me. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I do not know go-ethereum code, but usually applications do this over JSON-RPC API, not matter the language.

Comment: go-etherium [supports](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/pubsub) publish / subscribe using JSON-RPC notifications. Have you looked at the [tests](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/3f74c8e0e504fe7606bc970dff71cf1266a4a9ed/rpc/subscription_test.go#L49-L124) for the subscription? It seems a good place to start.